# Sockets UDP - Calcular cuadrado de un numero recibido

Tags: java, netbeans, tcpudp

Utilizando sockets UDP, tengo que crear un programa cliente que introduzca por teclado un número entero y se lo envíe al servidor. El servidor tiene que devolver el cuadrado del número.

Mi problema es que no me funciona, pues en la clase Servidor me da error el código *int numero = new int(recibo.getData());*, y en la clase Cliente me da error el código *enviados = numero.getBytes();*. He comprobado que el problema con el error de la clase Servidor es el int, puesto que si escribo un *String cadena = new String(recibo.getData()).trim();* no da error, pero en este caso es un int lo que recibe no un String.

¿Cómo podria solucionarlo? ¿Debo hacerlo de otro modo?

**Clase Servidor**

```
    public class Servidor {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
            // ASOCIO EL SOCKET AL PUERTO 12345
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);
    
            // ESPERANDO DATAGRAMA 
            System.out.println("Servidor esperando datagrama... ");
            DatagramPacket recibo;
    
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            recibo = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            // RECIBO DATAGRAMA
            socket.receive(recibo);
    
            int numero = new int(recibo.getData());
            System.out.println("Servidor recibe el numero: " + numero);
    
            // CALCULAR EL CUADRADO DEL NUMERO RECIBIDO
            int cuadrado = numero * numero;
    
            // DIRECCIÓN ORIGEN DEL MENSAJE 
            InetAddress IPOrigen = recibo.getAddress();
            int puerto = recibo.getPort();
    
            // ENVIANDO DATAGRAMA AL CLIENTE
            System.out.println("Enviando el cuadrado del numero -> " + cuadrado);
            // PASO ENTERO A BYTE
            byte b = (byte) cuadrado;
            byte[] enviados = new byte[1024];
            enviados[0] = b;
    
            DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket(enviados, enviados.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
            socket.send(envio);
    
            // CERRAR EL SOCKET
            System.out.println("Cerrando conexion... ");
            socket.close();
        }
    }
```

**Clase Cliente**

```
public class Cliente {

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        DatagramSocket clienteSocket = new DatagramSocket();
         
         // DATOS DEL SERVIDOR AL QUE ENVIAR EL MENSAJE
         InetAddress IPServidor = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
         // PUERTO POR EL QUE ESCUCHA
         int puerto = 12345;
         
         // INTRODUCIR DATOS POR TECLADO
         System.out.println("Introduce el numero: ");
         int numero = sc.nextInt();
         
         byte[] enviados = new byte[1024];
         // CONVERTIR CADENA A BYTES
         enviados = numero.getBytes();
         
         // ENVIANDO DATAGRAMA AL SERVIDOR 
         DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket(enviados, enviados.length, IPServidor, puerto);
         clienteSocket.send(envio);
         
         // RECIBIENDO DATAGRAMA DEL SERVIDOR
         byte[] recibidos = new byte[8];
         DatagramPacket recibo = new DatagramPacket(recibidos, recibidos.length, IPServidor, puerto);
         System.out.println("Esperando datagrama... ");
         clienteSocket.receive(recibo);
         
         // OBTENER EL CUADRADO DEL NUMERO ENVIADO
         byte[] hh = recibo.getData();
         int num = hh[0];
         System.out.println("Recibo el cuadrado del numero --> " + num);
         
         // CERRAR EL SOCKET 
         clienteSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes recibirlo como String y parsearlo a Integer

Comment: lo probé y tampoco sirve, al ejecutarlo esta vez da error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en la clase Servidor es que estas intentando convertir un array de bytes en un entero usando el constructor `new int()`

Puedes utilizar la clase `ByteBuffer` en su lugar:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(recibo.getData());
int numero = bb.getInt();
```

En la clase Cliente utiliza la misma clase para convertir el entero en un array de bytes:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
bb.putInt(numero);
byte[] enviados = bb.array();
```

De esta forma, estás creando un array de 4 bytes (el tamaño de un entero) y luego colocando el valor del entero en el array usando el método `putInt()`. Luego, puedes obtener el array de bytes usando el método `array()`.

**Clase Servidor:**

```
public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        // ASOCIO EL SOCKET AL PUERTO 12345
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);

        // ESPERANDO DATAGRAMA 
        System.out.println("Servidor esperando datagrama... ");
        DatagramPacket recibo;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        recibo = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        // RECIBO DATAGRAMA
        socket.receive(recibo);

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(recibo.getData());
        int numero = bb.getInt();
        System.out.println("Servidor recibe el numero: " + numero);

        // CALCULAR EL CUADRADO DEL NUMERO RECIBIDO
        int cuadrado = numero * numero;

        // DIRECCIÓN ORIGEN DEL MENSAJE 
        InetAddress IPOrigen = recibo.getAddress();
        int puerto = recibo.getPort();

        // ENVIANDO DATAGRAMA AL CLIENTE
        System.out.println("Enviando el cuadrado del numero -> " + cuadrado);
        // PASO ENTERO A BYTE
        ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        bb2.putInt(cuadrado);
        byte[] enviados = bb2.array();

        DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket(enviados, enviados.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
        socket.send(envio);

        // CERRAR EL SOCKET
        System.out.println("Cerrando conexion... ");
        socket.close();
    }
}

**Clase Cliente:**
public class Cliente {

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        DatagramSocket clienteSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        // DATOS DEL SERVIDOR AL QUE ENVIAR EL MENSAJE
        InetAddress IPServidor = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        // PUERTO POR EL QUE ESCUCHA
        int puerto = 12345;

        // INTRODUCIR DATOS POR TECLADO
        System.out.println("Introduce el numero: ");
        int numero = sc.nextInt();

        // ENVIANDO DATAGRAMA AL SERVIDOR 
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        bb.putInt(numero);
        byte[] enviados = bb.array();

        DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket(enviados, enviados.length, IPServidor, puerto);
        clienteSocket.send(envio);

        // RECIBIENDO DATAGRAMA DEL SERVIDOR
        byte[] recibidos = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket recibo = new DatagramPacket(recibidos, recibidos.length, IPServidor, puerto);
        System.out.println("Esperando datagrama... ");
        clienteSocket.receive(recibo);

        // OBTENER EL CUADRADO DEL NUMERO ENVIADO
        ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(recibo.getData());
        int num = bb2.getInt();
        System.out.println("Recibo el cuadrado del numero --> " + num);

        // CERRAR EL SOCKET 
        clienteSocket.close();
    }
}
```

PD: He actualizado las variables que se utilizan para el envío/recibo de datos.